# Add an instance of a current widget class into another instance while in the constructor

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I am working with Kivy in Python and I am trying to do something similar to this:

```
class CustomWidget1(Screen):
    body = ObjectProperty()  # An id object referencing a nested widget inside the .kv file

class CustomWidget2(Screen):    
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        CustomWidget1().body.add_widget(..HOW?..)  # THIS is what I need to figure out
```

**My Goal:**

Inside the constructor of `CustomWidget2`, how can I add the current instance of `CustomWidget2` as a widget inside the `body` widget of `CustomWidget1`?

To give an example of something I tried, but didn't work:

```
CustomWidget1().body.add_widget(self)
```

**Things to note:**

- Both `CustomWidget1` and `CustomWidget2` have their associated `.kv` file with stuff in it.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: thanks for the info @eyllanesc I am new here, this can be useful later. However, just to be clear, everything I provided works correctly as I expect. I just haven't figured how to get that last part to work the way I want it to work.

Comment: If you want help you must provide an MRE **now**, if you do not ask your question it will be off-topic so it will probably be closed. I recommend you read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour] if you have not done so.